# Connection closed before finished query (Spark/Scala and mapPartition)

Tags: postgresql, scala, apache-spark, jdbc

Recently I started a new project that I use JDBC with Spark. In my project I need perform some queries on Postgres and I can't use spark.read.format or spark.read.jdbc to get data.

```scala
private def seekData(
    rows: Iterator[Row],
    whereClause: String,
    dbConf: DBConnectionData,
    schema: Array[String]): Iterator[(StructType, Row)] = {
  val connection = DriverManager.getConnection(dbConf.url,dbConf.user, dbConf.password)
  val queryStatement = connection.prepareStatement(whereClause)
  val data = rows.flatMap { row =>
    val resultSet = setParameters(queryStatement, row, schema)
    val rowList = resultSetToSchemaAndRows(resultSet)
    resultSet.close()
    rowList
  }
  data match {
    case data if data.hasNext =>
      queryStatement.close()
      connection.close()
      data
    case _ =>
      queryStatement.close()
      connection.close()
      Iterator.empty
  }
}
```

The impression I have is that since this function is being called within a mapPartition, it's as if when the processing of the first partition closes the connection, it impacts the other partitions and ends up raising a "Connection is closed" error. If I open the connection outside of the mapPartition, it raises a Serialization error. How can I solve this problem?